# Fail2ban regex for special log format

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I have a log file with lines that look like this:

```
2019-12-21 20:30:02 index [WARNING]: authenticate: failed login attempt {"action":"login","username":"tgbtgbtgbtgb","ip":"61.142.184.152"} - {"file":"Login.php","line":147, ...
```

I set up a filter in Fail2ban with the following regex:

```
\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" index [WARNING]: authenticate: failed login attempt {\"action\":\"login\",\"username\":\".*\",\"ip\":\"<HOST>\".*
```

Unfortunately, Fail2ban can't catch the failed log in attempts based on the regex above. What can be wrong ?

The configuration block in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` is:

```
[appname]
enabled  = true
filter   = appname
logpath  = /path/to/logfile.log
port     = 80,443
maxretry = 3
bantime = 259200
```

Also, the log file is readable by Fail2ban. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Fail2ban removes timestamp matched `datepattern` from the string before the search for match of `failregex` begins.
So you can just remove `\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"`.

Or better use something like this:

```regex
failregex = ^\s*\S*\s+\[WARNING\]: authenticate: failed login attempt \{(?:"(?!ip")[^"]+":(?:"(?:[^"]|\\")*(?!\\)"|[^,]*),\s*)*"ip":"<HOST>"
```

This is a bit more safe - ahead anchored, as well as it would match if part that looks like json would change in-between (order of tags, etc).
Part `(?:"(?!ip")[^"]+":(?:"(?:[^"]|\\")*(?!\\)"|[^,]*),\s*)*` is a "simple" matcher for json dict elements bypassing any tag excepting `"ip"`.

Comment: Thank you sebres ! This indeed works. I found that  failregex = ^.*authenticate\: failed login attempt.*\"ip\"\:\"<HOST>\".*$  also works. On another note: I understand that you maintain Fail2ban: thank you once again! I really appreciate the work of Fail2ban developers. Fail2ban is of vital importance for any application with a public facing log in page. Keep up the good work!